# Why is this comparison illegal/objectionable

Tags: pointers, comparison

Here is the jist of my code...

```
    #define RAM_LOC 0x500000
    ...
    ...
    volatile int my_func(void)
    {
    <something in here>
    }
    ...
    ...
main()
{
    if(&my_func >= RAM_LOC && &my_func <= RAM_LOC + 10) <-- Warning here
    ...
    ...
}
```

I get a warning about the comparison and it is as follows:
"warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast"

My question is why is this illegal.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it expects you to define 0x500000 as a function pointer or an array pointer  so it can continue checking successfully or giving another warning because of a C++11 standard being more strict?.

Comment: What would be the syntax? Can you suggest examples?  Thanks

Comment: just casting to function pointer